# password recovery control in asp.net using gmail smtp server settings - the message appears on the website instead of emailing

Tags: asp.net

Please bear with me I'm new to ASP.NET. Here is what i did,

WEB.CONFIG

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
   <smtp from="mygmail@gmail.com">
   <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="mygmailpwd" 
     userName="mygmail@gmail.com" enableSsl="true"/>
   </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

PASSWORDRECOVERYRES.ASPX

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PasswordRecoveryRes.aspx.cs" Inherits="PasswordRecovery" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<h1> Forgot Your Password?</h1>
    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" 
        onsendingmail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail" 
        onsendmailerror="PasswordRecovery1_SendMailError" 
        onverifyinganswer="PasswordRecovery1_VerifyingAnswer" 
        onverifyinguser="PasswordRecovery1_VerifyingUser">
        <MailDefinition From="mygmail@gmail.com" Subject="Password Recovery">
        </MailDefinition>
    </asp:PasswordRecovery>
</asp:Content>
```

PASSWORDRECOVERYRES.ASPX.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class PasswordRecovery : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
  protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
  {
      PasswordRecovery1.SuccessText = e.Message.Body;
      e.Cancel = true;
  }
  protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendMailError(object sender, SendMailErrorEventArgs e)
  {

  }
  protected void PasswordRecovery1_VerifyingAnswer(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
  {

  }
  protected void PasswordRecovery1_VerifyingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
  {

  }
}
```

When I ran PASSWORDRECOVERYRES.ASPX I didnt get any error. The following message gets displayed

```
"Please return to the site and log in using the following information. User Name: username1 Password: %#;IXWh3b:Zj$:"
```

But shouldn't this message be emailed to username1@gmail.com from mygmail@gmail.com? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your SendingMail event (`PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail`) you first copy the mail body to the control and then you cancel the event (which prevents the email from being sent).

What's suprising is that these two actions are the only user code in your code behind and you still ask why it doesn't work. It works, exactly as you have implemented it. Comment these two lines of code and you will most probably get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.aspx

```
protected void PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
{
    PasswordRecovery1.SuccessText = "Mail Sent Successfully!!";
}
```